# Как заменять значения элементов в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Например есть список:

```
lst = [[1, 0], [0, 0, 2]]
```

Как заменить все нули, чтобы стало:

```
lst = [[1, 1], [1, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: eval(str(lst).replace('0', '1'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = [[1,0],[0,0,2]]
newLst = [[1 if j == 0 else j for j in i] for i in lst]
print(newLst)
```

Вернет

```
[[1, 1], [1, 1, 2]]
```